# Objects Colliding

Tags: c++, qt, object, collision-detection

I am creating a function that checks if cars are colliding and if they are their speed is reduced. It works with different car types but not when the same car type hits the same car type they both just stop

This method is constantly being called with a timer.

basically if **car** hits **carwithtrailer** the car slows down.

But if **car** hits **car** they both just stop because its the same object.

---> the last logic in the if statement is the problem

```
            !(typeid(*(colliding_items2[i]))==  typeid(this))
```

---

```
      QList<QGraphicsItem *> colliding_items2 = collidingItems();
for(int i=0, n= colliding_items2.size();i<n;++i){
    if(((typeid(*(colliding_items2[i]))== typeid(carwithtrailer)) ||(typeid(*(colliding_items2[i]))== typeid(car)) ) && (!(typeid(*(colliding_items2[i]))==  typeid(this)) )){
      speedOfCar = speedOfCar-1;
        return; 
 }
}
```

I want to check that if it is hitting the same object type it wont just stop.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `typeid` of `this` is going to be a pointer type. Since you are dereferencing the things in the array I don't think this is what you want.

Comment: The physics of two objects colliding frontal is just that (a full stop of both), with some energy and matter transformation, too.

Comment: typeid works off declared class and thus you won't get the polymorphic behavior you are looking for. dynamic_cast is one way to go (other is to roll out your own RTTI)

Comment: See I want it to invoke a different method if it hits the same object type so they both dont just stop

Comment: Why don't you just add an integer member variable to the base class that stores an ID describing the type of vehicle, then you can do all kinds of conditional comparisons.

Comment: If you were to employ polymorphism correctly, you shouldn't even have to know the types of the things that are colliding. This smells a bit to me. If you ever have to add new car types, you have to add new conditional statements to your program querying the typeid...

Comment: If they are `QObject`s, you can check if their `metaObject()->className()` are the same.

Comment: @Steve Yes we have all the cars inheriting from type Vehicle which solves that but we changed it because of what happens when the same object collides with the same object both just stop